# In mutt, can't bind `limit` in pager to a key, but `next-line` binds fine; what's the problem?

Tags: mutt

I am trying to make `limit` available in pager.

mutt thinks there is some error in `bind pager l limit` but `bind pager k next-line` works just fine. Any way to find out what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this keybinding:

```
bind index l limit
```

This is already the default behavior in mutt.

Since mutt has a different set of bindings for the pager, the index, the attachment view and so on, you need to specify the right map you want to modify when you bind a key.

Comment: I am aware of the default key binding. I would like l for <limit> to work in both index and pager, and `bind index,pager l limit` does not work either.

Comment: `index`: list the emails of an opened folder, it's the main mode. `pager`: display a selected e-mail. Each mode has its own set of actions and only some actions are available in more than one mode. As far as I know, `limit` can only be defined for `index` mode, so `bind index,pager l limit` doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

`limit` is not available in the pager (unless it has been added very recently).

You can check this yourself by hitting `?` when having a message open in the pager. It will show you a list of all commands that you can bind in that mode; you will see that `limit` is not listed even under the heading `Unbound functions`.

However, if you do the same in the message index, you will see that `limit` *is* available (and likely bound).

So unfortunately what you want is not possible, unless you are willing to hack the source code to implement support for `limit` in pager mode.